# Finding palindromes by adding its reversed to itself through x to y doing only depth number of calculation

Tags: ruby, loops, reverse, palindrome

I'm having trouble doing a challenge in ruby about palindromes.

I actually looked too many sources and i think my brain **melted** a bit as i am a novice programmer.

Lemme sum up the question :

So from user we get beginning value ending value, and a depth value.We take the beginning value and check If the number is a **palindrome**,if it isn't then we add its **reversed** to **itself**( 20, reverse(20)=02, add , 22) and check the number we find if its a palindrome.If it isn't we take the calculated number and add its **reversed** to **itself**.But we only can do that "depth" value times.
And print if we find a palindrome through those calculations we print value ----> xxxx if not we print value ----> special number.

I'm able to find palindromes, through given and ending value.But i just cant implement the depth thing.My problem looks a lot like [Setting a Limit on loops and calculating palindromes in C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747756/setting-a-limit-on-loops-and-calculating-palindromes-in-c-programming) but since i'm a ruby novice i cant make sense of C for now.Any help will be appreciated.

Edit : We do that like x to y , beginning value to ending value, like if they type 20 as beginning and 30 as ending value, we check 20 if its a palindrome add its reversed etc.Once we finish checking it we check the next number, 21 then 22,23... to 30.

Comment: Please edit to explain what the "ending value" is and how it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def doit(n, max_tries)
  max_tries.times.each do
    rev = n.to_s.reverse.to_i 
    (n == rev) ? (return n) : n += rev
  end
  nil
end

doit(22,   1)   #=> 22

doit(21,   1)   #=> nil
doit(21,   2)   #=> 33

doit(137,  1)   #=> nil
doit(137,  2)   #=> 868

doit(1373, 2)   #=> nil 
doit(1373, 3)   #=> 9119

doit(13732,  9) #=> nil 
doit(13732, 10) #=> 134202431
```

Comment: Could you explain what .each do in 2nd line?

Comment: Suppose `max_tries = 2`. Then `enum = max_tries.times #=> 2.times #=> => #<Enumerator: 2:times>`. We can see the elements that `enum` will pass to the block by converting it to an array: `enum.to_a #=> [0, 1] `. I could have instead written `0.upto(max_tries-1).each` or `(0...max_times).each` (note three dots in the latter).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer from @Cary Swoveland i manage to solve my problem:

```
def doit(n, max_tries)
  max_tries.times.each do
      print "#{n} "
      rev = n.to_s.reverse.to_i 
    (n == rev) ? (return n) : n += rev
  end
  nil
end

def revadd
  puts "Give me a starting integer"
  beginningvalue = gets.to_i
  puts "Give me a ending integer"
  endingvalue = gets.to_i
  puts "Give me a depth"
  depth = gets.to_i
    array = (beginningvalue..endingvalue-1).to_a
     for i in array
       if(doit(i,depth) != nil)
       puts ""
       print "#{i} ---> xxxx "
       puts ""
       else 
       puts ""
       print "#{i} ---> special number"
       puts ""
    end # end if
  end # end for
end # end def
revadd
```